# getText() method doesn't work with integers

Tags: java

```
textfield2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionevent)
    {
        String input = textfield2.getText();
        Output2.setText("Your age is " + (2017-input));
    }
});

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actioneven)
    {
        String input = textfield2.getText();
        Output2.setText("Your age is " + (2017 -input));
    }
});
```

I am trying to get a number from the user (an integer) and subtract that number from 2017. It gives an error saying that it is a String and I can't subtract a number from a String. When I change `String input` to `int input` it gives errors again. It says that I can't use `getText()`. I've tried few ways such as `parseInt()` and it did not work. How can I fix this problem?

My Question is different from [How to convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java) because I looked at the answers there and they didn't really work with my code.

Comment: Did you try similar to this `(2017 -Integer.parseInt(input))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert the `String` obtained from the TextField to `Integer`

You can do that by

- `Integer.parseInt(string);`
- `Integer.valueOf(string);`

In you case you can do like this.

```
 Output2.setText("Your age is " + (2017 - Integer.parseInt(input)));
```

or

```
Output2.setText("Your age is " + (2017 - Integer.valueOf(input)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, you helped me a lot. I was using parseInt() wrong.

Comment: Happy to hear. Accept the answer if it worked.!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the input first before subtracting it

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText());
Output2.setText("Your age is " + (2017 -input));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped and solved my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help